# Change "Note to self" email address

Tags: gmail, google-maps, google-now, notes

When I ask my phone to "take a note" or say "note to self" from Google Now or Google Maps, it asks me what the note is, and then it emails me the note at a specific email address that I designated a long time ago. This is a non-Google email address, by the way.

It works fine, but I now want to change the email address that the note is sent to. For the life of me, I can't remember where I set the destination email address years ago, and I can't find where to change it now.

Where is this setting found?

I do NOT have Google Keep installed, so I assume that this feature is associated with Gmail, but I'm not 100% sure.  Where do I go to see/change which which app is associated with "take a note" / "note to self"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the answer. The option was a lot more buried than I thought it would be.

1. Open the Google app on your phone.
2. Press the More (hamburger) menu button, then choose "Settings".
3. Under "Google Assistant", tap "Settings".
4. Switch to the "Assistant" tab, then tap "Routines".
5. Scroll through the list and find "Take a Note" or whatever your command is and tap on it.
6. Under "My assistant should...", you should see, "email ". Tap on the gear next to it and edit the email address.
7. Tap then back arrow, then tap the check mark to save the change.